# Windows: How to use hosts file with path?

Tags: hosts-file

This works:

```
127.0.0.1       www.somesite.com
```

But not this:

```
127.0.0.1/somepath/www       www.mysite.com
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to map a full path like this? If not, what is the easiest way to accomplish what I want to do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't use the hosts file to redirect to specific URLs. It can only be used to map *hostnames* to *IP addresses*.

Comment: Is there a way to do it though? Some other way?

Comment: @coderama you could use internal rewrite/mod_proxy to do the same on server side. I'm not aware of any solutions doing it on client side.