# How can I change a localhost URL with mod_rewrite or mod_proxy?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp, mod-proxy

I've got MAMP running (Apache:80 MySQL:3306), and my localhost has a number of folders containing projects:

127.0.0.1/
127.0.0.1/test1/
127.0.0.1/test2/

I've got my hosts file setup properly so jlc.dev/test1 and jlc.dev/test2 are working fine.

Where I'm having trouble is I'd like to have the URL test1.dev to run the app at /test1 and the URL test2.dev to run the app at /test2. (*I'm not sure what the right term is there, but I hope I've got the point across.)* Based on one of the responses in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476400/windows-how-to-use-hosts-file-with-path), it sounds like it can be achieved with mod_proxy or mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file.

What I'm assuming I do is direct test1.dev to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file, and have an .htaccess file that looks at the referring domain and rewrites to /test1 appropriately.

Little help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to direct both `test1.dev` and `test2.dev` to 127.0.0.1. Then add this to the htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.dev$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1::%1 !^([^/]*)/.*::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hmm, that seems to return a 500 error on everything at (localhost) 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks @JonLin that's perfect. I was playing with that open parentheses, but couldn't find the right place to close it. Haha. Many thanks.